# store list of articles and generate random one each time?

Tags: android, database, list, arraylist, random

What I want to do exactly is when button gets clicked it goes to another activity using the "Intent" and then it generates a random article from my list of articles and then display it on screen. please just put me on the right direction and I will start researching myself because I am really stuck at the research part.

Can I use ArrayList and random from it in this case or it will be hard? or do I need to create a database for example?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
Random rand = new Random();
String random = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the reference or content (I do not know what the Strings in your above ArrayList exactly shall represent) of your random article as a parameter in the Intent to open your new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("article_string", random);
startActivity(intent);
```

Keep in mind that passing a large amount of data with an intent might not be a good software architecture if that data could be referenced from a shared data source.

Comment: Thank you Norbert, but do i need to implement it in the "Intent" itself? what if i want to random the article in the "Activity" that the intent refers to? i mean when button get clicked the intent take it to the next Activity and then the Activity displays a random article.

Comment: In case the new activity should randomly choose an article, I suggest both activities should share a common data source for the articles you can implement with a singleton class that you can manage within your application class. And in case you want to make the data persistent use a local SQLite database to store the data in the filesystem (which you can manage yourself or with libraries e.g. http://greenrobot.org/greendao/).